# Determing caller ID from DoDataExchange in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to implement a function that behaves differently for different IDs from my menu resources. For example:

```
ON_COMMAND(ID_1, Func)
ON_COMMAND(ID_2, Func)
ON_COMMAND(ID_3, Func)


void Func()
{
switch(id)
case ID_1:
//DO THIS
break;

case ID_2:
//DO THAT
break;
...
```

Is there any way to determine the ID of the calling resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `ON_COMMAND_RANGE` macro. Message handler has `UINT nID` parameter:

```
afx_msg void Func(UINT nID);

ON_COMMAND_RANGE(ID_1, ID_3, Func)
```

Note: this macro is not supported by MFC Application Wizard, you need to add it manually. Resource ID range must be contiguous.